# Scala Play: How to get the current protocol, ip and port outside the scope of a request?

Tags: scala, playframework

I know it's possible to get the current protocol, ip and port within the scope of a request like this:

```
implicit val request: RequestHeader
play.api.mvc.Call(request.method, "").absoluteURL()
```

but I don't have a request in context. My use-case is an application module that on startup indexes the WebApp for the search functionality so I have no request in scope.

However, this information should "be known" to Play at that point anyways correct? Is there an API to get it?

**UPDATE:** Ok I think it's safe to assume that the IP is the current node `0.0.0.0`, `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`. These will work in any either the development environment or when deployed in Heroku. Now I only need the port and protocol.

Comment: What would be the goal?

Comment: @cchantep I said it, index the WebApp on start up using Lucene ...

Comment: Why would that be required to index?

Comment: Because you don't want to index Play template tags but the actual content and actual links.

Comment: Still unclear, if the content is accessible by different domain, the path should be kept relative to be rendered properly in the search result

Comment: I don't need to store the host and port etc indeed I only store the relative path but I need the host and port to do the crawling. I can't crawl relative URLs I need a valid starting point.

Comment: Then just configure a default host/port on the indexer side ...

Comment: I wanted to avoid hardcoding values or even configuring them while there would be API's to get them in the first place. My OP is about learning those APIs.